# Postgres Aggregate Hstore

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Postgres and I'm working on an existing Laravel application. The entries table uses an `hstore` column called `data`. This is the offending query:

```
$query = \DB::table('entries')
        ->where('f_id', '=', $f->id)
        ->where('s_id', '=', \Config::get('s_id'))
        ->select(\DB::raw('SUM(CAST("data"->\'total\' as decimal)) as "total"'))
        ->get();
```

I can see what they're doing here, but this piece of code fails with the error:

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: \"\" (SQL: select SUM(CAST(\"data\"->'total' as decimal)) as \"total\" from \"entries\" where \"f_id\" = 70 and \"s_id\" = 1)
```

I can't figure out why, could anyone explain the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`NULLIF`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) to take care of empty strings:

```
'SUM(NULLIF("data"->\'total\', '')::numeric)) as "total"'
```

Can make the sum NULL as well, if *all* fields are NULL.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as this actually solves my issue. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was not the actual query.

The issue was the "total" entry was empty, which when casted to a decimal caused the error.